# How does cooking work in D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, food-and-drink

So, I haven't played in *forever*, but a few friends and I have been talking about playing 5e again. I've been the DM, and they've been requesting a cook off since the beginning.
**How does cooking work in D&D?**
I have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: Which books do you have access to?  Welcome to RPGSE.  Please take a look at the [tour], [help], [ask] and [answer] to see how to get the most from an SE formatted site.  Is it your intention to make cooking a part of an adventure that results in an achievement or a reward for the party?  In other words, is the cook off like the [Terlingua Chili Cookoff](https://www.texasmonthly.com/the-culture/terlingua-chili-cook-off-at-the-fifty/), a public competition, or is this a contest between party members?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153320/which-ability-applies-to-cooking-meals-with-cooks-utensils

Comment: For inspiration you might want to look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_in_Dungeon and then there is Heroes' Feast (Dungeons & Dragons): The Official D&D Cookbook, ISBN-13 : 978-1984858900.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 16):

#### Make an ability check, adding your proficiency bonus if you are proficient with cook's utensils.

For general cooking, they aren't really any rules. There is a tool listed in the equipment section of the PHB called Cook's Utensils, and the rules for tools state:

> A tool helps you to do something you couldn't otherwise do, such as craft or repair an item, forge a document, or pick a lock. Your race, class, background, or feats give you proficiency with certain tools. Proficiency with a tool allows you to add your proficiency bonus to any ability check you make using that tool. Tool use is not tied to a single ability, since proficiency with a tool represents broader knowledge of its use. For example, the DM might ask you to make a Dexterity check to carve a fine detail with your woodcarver's tools, or a Strength check to make something out of particularly hard wood.

So the rules do not tell us what ability is associated with cooking, so that is up to you, the DM. If a character has proficiency with Cook's Utensils, they may add their proficiency bonus to the check.

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* adds a little bit more to Cook's Utensils, though it isn't much, and it isn't really relevant to having a cook off.

*Tasha' Cauldron of Everything* (released Nov. 2020) adds a feat called *Chef* that significantly expands the usefulness of Cook's Utensils, but doesn't contribute much to a cook off, except possibly a narrative argument that a character with the Feat should always win a cook off against someone without the feat, but that would be your call as the DM.

#### For a cook off, use the rules for contests.

The rules do contain some general guidance for skill contests, so use these rules and the Cook's Utensils check described above for your cook off:

> Sometimes one character's or monster's efforts are directly opposed to another's. This can occur when both of them are trying to do the same thing and only one can succeed, such as attempting to snatch up a magic ring that has fallen on the floor. This situation also applies when one of them is trying to prevent the other one from accomplishing a goal — for example, when a monster tries to force open a door that an adventurer is holding closed. In situations like these, the outcome is determined by a special form of ability check, called a contest.
>
> Both participants in a contest make ability checks appropriate to their efforts. They apply all appropriate bonuses and penalties, but instead of comparing the total to a DC, they compare the totals of their two checks. The participant with the higher check total wins the contest. That character or monster either succeeds at the action or prevents the other one from succeeding.
>
> If the contest results in a tie, the situation remains the same as it was before the contest. Thus, one contestant might win the contest by default. If two characters tie in a contest to snatch a ring off the floor, neither character grabs it. In a contest between a monster trying to open a door and an adventurer trying to keep the door closed, a tie means that the door remains shut.

So have the two characters make the check, and the higher result wins the contest, but obviously, make it more interesting than saying "you win" - get creative with your narration, maybe watch some Gordon Ramsay videos before hand to work up your food critic vocabulary.

Comment: You might consider stealing "skill challenges" from 4e and modifying it slightly. Maybe an Intelligence and/or Insight check to pick the right ingredients (if given limited ingredients and/or to read the judges), followed by Dex (with tool and/or prof bonus) for preparing the food, and finally Persuasion for plating/presentation. For something like this rather than simple pass/fail for each check I'd add up each person's margin of success.

Comment: @aslum If youve got experience running those, that would be a helpful answer. I dont have any experience running those.

Comment: I usually find skill challenges don't work very well in D&D's system. I've tried them out, and IMO it was a lot of time and effort to put into something that didn't make for fun play. The players felt like there was a disconnect between the arbitrary number of successes needed to win the encounter and the story of what was happening. It may work in some circumstances, but it was such an awkward fit that I really haven't ever used them again. Now I just set the scene and let the players and dice determine how things play out without having a specific number of successes or failures in mind.

Comment: This answer misses the most common use of cooking: As a background activity that's part of making camp and which you don't usually bother rolling for because there's no meaningful difference between success and failure. Some newbie GMs and players make the mistake of thinking you need to roll for *everything*, so it's a good idea to clear up that misunderstanding.

Comment: @GMJoe I left it out as OP seems to be asking about the mechanical specifics of cooking, particularly in the context of a cook-off. There are a lot of things I’ve left out that are technically about cooking, but they are non-specific to OP’s apparent problem.

Answer (score 5):

### Talk to players and find out how much they time they want to invest in a cooking challenge.

Thomas Markov has a perfectly fine answer for a quick resolution. If your players are looking for something a bit more involved then a simple opposed skill test you might consider stealing "skill challenges" from 4e (modifying it slightly to fit your game).

While I haven't done an Iron Chef style cooking challenge, I have run other mini-contests that wanted more story then just a simple opposed check.

For a cook off I might suggest:

- **Intelligence** check to pick the right ingredients (assuming limited ingredients or weird requirements like MUST use cockatrice eggs)
- **Insight** to read the judges
- **Dexterity** (with tool/prof bonus) for preparing the food
- **Persuasion** for plating/presentation.

For something like this rather than simple pass/fail for each check I'd add up each person's margin of success. This can add to the excitement if you go step by step and narrate each persons successes/failures as you go.

Example:

> Player A beats Player B by 3 in the Intelligence check. "It looks like
> B hasn't properly chilled the Cockatrice Eggs prior to cracking and
> now she's going to have to deal with all those shell fragments, will
> she be able to recover?
>
> Player B beats A by 5 on the Insight (now B is ahead by 2). "Well, A
> has chosen to go heavily on the spiced chilis, but I guess he didn't
> realize that Grog the Barbarian (one of the judges) isn't a fan of
> spicy food."

And so on.

Finally, while Halflings from Eberron can have the Hospitality Dragonmark, in game guidance to exactly how it aides in cooking is mostly limited to it giving a d4 bonus die to related checks. Keep in mind that if you do a skill challenge and allow it to be used on every roll it'll give that player a pretty large advantage (I might disallow it for the final Persuasion check).

Comment: I thought immediately of the 4e skill challenges idea, but do not have sufficient familiarity with that method to have made an answer. Thanks for adding this, it helped me if nobody else. 

Comment: TBH the strictness of Skill Challenges never really set well with me, but as a loose framework it can work pretty great, especially for tasks that might be more complicated than a single check but where you want some structure.

Comment: we  had a skill challenge like  thing in ToA when nits was running that a few years ago.  (In our case, we had to perform in public an impromptu musical piece, as a group) We ended up doing something quite a bit like what you propose here.

Comment: +1. Pretty much any time the players want to face off in a scene, a skill challenge is the right answer. One minor thing you can add is point spread options that modify the challenge. If you think of a dartboard, there are smaller areas worth a lot of points. Using the example, you could let the players choose between chicken eggs (common but easy to deal with) or cockatrice eggs (a delicacy that's hard to get right) for additional drama. In the latter case, raise one or two DCs but give an extra success if they stick the landing.

Comment: This answer misses the most common use of cooking: As a background activity that's part of making camp and which you don't usually bother rolling for because there's no meaningful difference between success and failure. Some newbie GMs and players make the mistake of thinking you need to roll for everything, so it's a good idea to clear up that misunderstanding.

Comment: @GMJoe I was in particular referencing the portion of the question that said: "I've been the DM, and they've been requesting a cook off since the beginning." It seemed more integral to the question in the original version of the question.

Answer (score 3):

### While all of the other answers so far address handling cooking in 5e, I'd propose something more invested for a cook-off.

When it comes to fun scenarios like a cook-off in a fantasy setting, you have the option to turn it into an event that can last you a few sessions. Based on running a cook-off scenario at my table before, I suggest turning the event into a small story arc. This arc combines three steps:

- Research.
- Resource Gathering.
- The main event cook-off.

In a 5e setting, you have many options to explore, using all kinds of exotic and difficult to obtain food supplies. Whether you are cooking [Cockatrice](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/cockatrice) eggs in [Sperm Whale](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sperm-whale) fat or choose something less dangerous like hunting down that merchant who, according to the rumours from that one gnome, owns a thousand-year-old egg that would demonstrate the luxury of your dish, is your choice. Maybe you also need that whisker-of-endless-swirling, rumoured to be found in an ancient valley that before it vanished from the maps, was home to a yearly celebration where they made a giant omelette in an equally humongous pan. You can tailor this event and adjust it to any level, utilising combat or social encounters.

For the main event, I suggest using a narrative-driven display of skill rather than a skill check based driven narrative. This narrative style has the advantage of determining the cook-off's results by the creativity of your players instead of their rolling dice. This style gives you the option to make a satisfying conclusion for all players involved based on their involvement with the event. To further that goal, you may want to take player's input on who should eventually win the cook-off - or if there even is a single winner. Perhaps one player is smart enough to bribe the judges while everyone else was too busy to notice while preparing the perfect dishes?

**The most important aspect of this process is understanding what your table enjoys and bringing it into a cooperative effort.** My players naturally worked together to achieve their individual goals to complete tasks to gather and compose their dishes. As the DM, you have to make sure that all players have options to further their goals regardless of where the party ends up spending time. You do not want an individual task for everybody that splits the party and turns your group session into tiny one on one sessions - keep your group involved by arranging events that further the individual goals to converge. If one party member needs the whale fat, then another party member should want to tag along because the whale hunter that the group seeks out also knows the secret technique of roasting the spices that another character wants to use in their dish. But the hunter will only reveal that information after a specific whale meets its end. As the DM, you are responsible to a degree to tie in motivations (but please also let your players help you by providing each other feedback and involving them in the discussion of setting up events).

### When should you roll to cook?

The DM describes the environment and the player describes that they want to cook. The DM decides and narrates the player character's actions.

[How to Play](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#HowtoPlay) (BR, p. 4):

> 1. The DM describes the environment.
> 2. The players describe what they want to do.
> 3. The DM narrates the results of the adventurers’ actions.

When it comes to cooking, you, as the DM, decide whether the players have a meaningful chance of failure, and only then do you roll. Many DMs do not bother to roll ability checks to cook individually, or they do a single roll to set up a camp that includes the more mundane aspects of travel like cooking the same dish that they prepared hundreds of times. You don't have to roll for activities that succeed every time.

[Ability Checks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AbilityChecks) (PHB, CH.7):

> An ability check tests a character’s or monster’s innate talent and
> training in an effort to overcome a challenge.  The DM calls for an
> ability check when a character or monster attempts an action (other
> than an attack) that has a chance of failure. When the outcome is
> uncertain, the dice determine the results.

Rolling die takes time, and it is easy to imagine a scenario where you get bogged down since you are rolling for everything because tangentially everything has *some sort of uncertainty in it* - imagine the absurdity of a DM making you roll for standing up in the morning, for collecting all your items in your tent, for folding together everything, for walking to the fire pit, for stoking the fire, for pouring your water in the pot, for boiling the water, and the list goes on.

**You roll a dice when there is a meaningful sort of failure that has tangible consequences.**

Imagine you are out of rations and anything that you can eat without preparing it while you are weathering the storm, you are cold and hungry, and somebody has to prepare those useless dry beans that you picked up in the comfort of the city. The consequences are concrete, exhaustion, hunger and the circumstances turn a usually mundane task into a test of a character’s innate talent and training in an effort to overcome the challenge.

In that case, you make an ability check, adding your proficiency bonus if you are proficient with cook's utensils.

> For every ability check, the DM decides which of the six abilities is
> relevant to the task at hand and the difficulty of the task,
> represented by a Difficulty Class.

### How about holding a Skill Contest?

A cook-off is a contest when it comes to plain English, but in 5e a cook-off hardly involves an [Ability Check Contest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Contests) in which you

> Sometimes one character's or monster's efforts are directly opposed to
> another's. This can occur when both of them are trying to do the same
> thing and only one can succeed [...]
>
> This situation also applies when one of them is trying to prevent the
> other one from accomplishing a goal--for example, when a monster tries
> to force open a door that an adventurer is holding closed. In
> situations like these, the outcome is determined by a special form of
> ability check, called a contest.

Your efforts are *not directly* opposed. They are *indirectly* opposed unless you want to hold a contest in which you are literally sabotaging each other.

Comment: This suggestion actually sounds kind of similar to the "Crafting an Item" downtime activity described in XGtE, particularly the part about acquiring a hard-to-get crafting component: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#CraftinganItem

Answer (score 1):

### The Chef's Utensils tool set

There is a tool proficiency for "Chef's Utensils". If you take that, then you're saying your character has some degree of training in cookery, and it would be appropriate to use that proficiency for a check to see how good your cooking is. Note that you don't need the proficiency to roll the dice -- if you don't have the proficiency, then it's just a straight ability score roll. The tool proficiency means you can add your proficiency bonus to the check, but lacking it would only stop you from making an attempt if there were a specific rule that said you had to have the proficiency to even try. As a DM, you might decide that some tasks are so complex and specific that you need it, such as making pastries or baking and decorating a wedding cake.

### What ability score do you roll?

Tool proficiencies are highly flexible in 5th edition; the ability score you roll when making a check with tools is largely up to the DM to determine if it isn't specified for a given task.

As an example, if you have a tool proficiency with the "playing card set" and you want to use that to win a game of chance, what ability score you use depends on your strategy. If you're trying to read your opponents' micro-expressions while keeping your own face carefully blank, Wisdom seems like an appropriate ability to use. If you're trying to bluff and manipulate your opponents by betting in specific ways and faking subtle reactions to your cards, then Charisma makes more sense. If you want to cheat, Dexterity might be the right skill to call for. I could even see an argument for Intelligence if you were going to try to count cards and play in a mathematically optimal manner, or Constitution if you're going to try to get your opposition drunk while you keep your head.

So if you want to ask for a cooking check, the same concept applies. Wisdom is probably the 'default' ability score to use since cooking is so much based on paying attention to your senses and a certain amount of intuition. But for a cooking contest (using the "Contests" rules found on page 174 of the *Player's Handbook*), encourage your players to play to their strengths by describing how they could use their abilities to make something impressive. I could see calling on Intelligence in some circumstances, or possibly even Dexterity, though it's hard to think of a way that Strength, Constitution, or Charisma might be made to play into cooking. Still, if your player can come up with a good story, I'd err on the side of allowing it.

### Going deeper

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* also has a section on expanded uses for tool proficiencies that suggests giving Advantage on a check if the character in question has both a skill and a tool proficiency that could apply to the task they're attempting. I'm not sure if any of the skills in the game would really apply to something like a cooking contest, but if one of your players happens to have an applicable skill and the utensils, maybe they could angle to get that advantage by explaining how they can use both together.

This is, however, an optional rule, so if you'd rather keep things simple, you can certainly ignore it.

Comment: This answer misses the most common use of cooking: As a background activity that's part of making camp and which you don't usually bother rolling for because there's no meaningful difference between success and failure. Some newbie GMs and players make the mistake of thinking you need to roll for everything, so it's a good idea to clear up that misunderstanding.

Comment: Since the OP was asking about a cook-off competition, my answer focused on how to handle rolls for cooking within the context of a legitimate contest, rather than when *not* to roll.